# How to extract hand tracking data from HoloLens2 into a data analysis format

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have been tasked with using Microsoft's MRTK and HoloLens2 to simply extract hand position data in the (X,Y,Z) coordinate axis system as well as hand movement data (acceleration, jerk, etc.) into a readable and analyzable format such as MS Excel.

Any help with the Microsoft MRTK and HoloLens2 API would be immensely helpful (especially with laying out the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [IMixedRealityHand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealityhand?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0) interface to request the joint data from the device. And this code shows how to poll joint pose from the controller: [Accessing a given hand controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#polling-joint-pose-from-controller)
For analyzing and tabulating, there is no out-of-box API from MRTK to do that, it needs to implement it by your own code. You can refer to this link to learn how to export the data to a CSV file: [Write Data From List To CSV File](https://forum.unity.com/threads/write-data-from-list-to-csv-file.643561/)

Comment: There are 7 different files but I can only see what they mean from their names but I am not sure what is what exactly.

Is there a wat to access files from hololens2 with Python?